# SSAS Cube Excel Pivot Table Hide Fields

Tags: sql, excel, pivot, ssas, cube

How do i hide an attribute from appearing as a field when creating a pivot table.

e.g. i dont want the user to see the PK of a dimension. Thanks

Comment: What version of Excel?  Excel 2003 vs 2007 vs 2010 vs 2013 all have increasing levels of functionality with pivot tables and connections to SSAS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within SSAS, set teh AttributeHierarchyVisible value to false on the value of the dimension that you wish to hide from client tools.  You will find this property available on each of the dimensions attributes.